# XRLabel text isn't displayed

Tags: c#, blazor, devexpress, xtrareport

My goal is to display labels on report page. Each report shows some info that is stored in the expression.
Now I have a list of options to choose from to customize the look of the report that set margins, width, height and pitches. From this data I then calculate the Page Size and apply it to the report.
The problem is the text in the labels only displayed when paper kind Id = 3 is applied (Letter).
When it comes to a4 or any other types - the page just looks divided into label sections with no text in them. Here is the code I use to create and fill labels:

```
DetailBand detail = new DetailBand();
            report.Bands.Add(detail);
            XRPanel panel = new XRPanel();
            panel.CanGrow = false;
            detail.Controls.Add(panel);
            panel.WidthF = labelWidth;
            panel.HeightF = labelHeight;
            panel.Borders = BorderSide.All;
            panel.Name = "Panel1";

            XRLabel lblMail = new XRLabel();
            lblMail.Name = "lblMail";
            lblMail.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            lblMail.HeightF = labelHeight;
            lblMail.WidthF = labelWidth;
            lblMail.CanGrow = false;
            lblMail.CanShrink = false;
            lblMail.Multiline = true;

            panel.Controls.Add(lblMail);
```

Here I fill the labels with the info from datasource:

```
XRLabel lblMail = (XRLabel)labelReport.FindControl("lblMail", false);
            string expression = "[OwnerName] + Char(10) + [Address1] + Char(10) + [Address2] + Char(10) + [City]" +
                " + ',' + [State] + ' ' + [Zip]";
            ExpressionBinding expressionBinding = new ExpressionBinding("BeforePrint", "Text", expression);
            lblMail.ExpressionBindings.Add(expressionBinding);
            

            labelReport.DataSource = reportSource;
```

So when this code is executed and the paper kind is anything but Letter I see this:

[image: instead of these blocks being filled with info]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It's unexpected that changing the paper type breaks control bindings. I'd recommend saving both results to REPX (XML) and then opening these files in the WinForms Report Designer to visually identify any differences. If this approach doesn't yield any results, consider posting your question on the DevExpress forum at devexpress.com/ask.